# How do I know which EL expression is triggering particular bean method?

Tags: jsf-2

There is a bean method which provides data for a number of `xthml` tags on a page. For debugging purposes I'd like to know which node in a `ViewRoot` is triggering the method. Something like that:

```
<ui:repeat id="alpha" value="#{myBean.objectList}" var="obj">
<!-- some stuff here -->
</ui:repeat>
```

and the method itself:

```
public List getObjectList() {
  String id = ????;
  logger.info("I'm being called by:" + id); // returning "alpha", "beta" 
                                            // or whatever component 
                                            // calling this method
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) to obtain the UI component instance currently being processed in the JSF lifecycle.

```
UIComponent currentComponent = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
String currentComponentId = currentComponent.getId();
// ...
```